# Kinect API written solely in Java without native functions?

Tags: java, kinect

Is there any open-source Java library, not written or ported from C or C++, or any C derivative, fully compatible with any platform (e.g. not containing assembly functions)?

The API needs to work on a cRIO module, and therefore can't have any x86 or x64 assembly.

Thanks!

Comment: Knowing Microsoft they will never implement a compatible SDK (because why make an API for a language they already copied). Hacker community will be the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no Kinect API written solely in java, nor would I expect one to be written in the foreseeable future that does not wrap another API.  If you would like to interact with the Kinect in java, looks like there is currently two main solutions.

1) Use the java wrappers for [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/), or 2) use the java wrappers for [OpenNI](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/tree/master/Wrappers/OpenNI.java).  From what I have read, the Kinect requires [these drivers](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect) for use with OpenNI.