# kinect API for controlling web applications

Tags: java, javascript, kinect

I would like to connect a kinect (sorry) to a PC so that users can interact with my webapp via gestures. I don't have a clear idea about what level of programming is involved in order to achieve this, but a JavaScript API would be ideal (Java would also be tolerable).

I've had a look at DepthJS, but the installation/setup alone has almost defeated me. At a minimum I need the user to be able to move the cursor and click, but ideally I'd also like them to be able to use smartphone gestures such as pinching.

Is there an API available that provides these features, can be installed/setup relatively easily, and can be programmed with JavaScript? I don't know if this makes any difference, but I'll be doing the development on Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe Gluegen could generate the Java JNI API for the kinect dlls. See http://jogamp.org/gluegen/www/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072810/kinect-api-written-solely-in-java-without-native-functions - have a look over here. Could be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kinesis](http://kinesis.io/) leverages web technologies developers already know best HTML/CSS/JavaScript. So you can reuse your existing code and existing team to build gesture enabled applications on top of Kinect for Windows SDK

[Zigfu](http://zigfu.com/en/) provides a browser plugin called ZigJS for Kinect and will enable HTML/JavaScript Kinect apps using hand gestures.

[OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) is an open community of people interested in making use of the amazing Xbox Kinect hardware with our PCs and other devices. They are working on free, open source libraries that will enable the Kinect to be used with Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Don about that

`At a minimum I need the user to be able to move the cursor and click, but ideally I'd also like them to be able to use smartphone gestures such as pinching.`

You`ll find many examples about Mouse cursos tracking. I think that connecting mouse to kinect is one of the first that kinect developer is trying to achive. This is very simple thing. You just connect cursor with one join, track him and scale it to monitor resolution :)

But I'm not sure that you want it . Even as a minimu. I remember that on channel9 I was watching movie about websites controlled by kinect. This technology exists for 100% and it's preaty stable. So you need just to look there.

IMO focus on api`a/frameworks for that. Cause connecting mouse to kinect just for using this on websites has many disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released new SDK 1.8 with Kinect.js library last September. I'm sure this is what you  need http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/09/16/updated-sdk-with-html5-kinect-fusion-improvements-and-more.aspx